# Cron Job with Whenever Gem, is failing in amazon elastic beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've installed the gem: whenever-elasticbeanstalk but I can't install it correctly, what's wrong?

> Errors:

```
[2015-02-03T22:34:04.789Z] INFO  [19261] - [CMD-

AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook] : Completed activity. Result:
  Successfully execute directory: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre.
[2015-02-03T22:34:04.789Z] INFO  [19261] - [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild] : Starting activity...
[2015-02-03T22:34:06.365Z] INFO  [19261] - [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild] : Activity execution failed, because: command failed with error code 1: Error occurred during build: Command cron_01_set_leader failed (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)
    at /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/executor-1.0/lib/executor/exec.rb:81:in `sh'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/executor-1.0/lib/executor/exec.rb:24:in `sh'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.0/lib/elasticbeanstalk/cfn-wrapper.rb:51:in `call_cfn_script'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.0/lib/elasticbeanstalk/cfn-wrapper.rb:28:in `run_config_sets'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.0/lib/elasticbeanstalk/infrahooks/infra-embeddedpostbuild.rb:20:in `execute!'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.0/lib/elasticbeanstalk/executable.rb:56:in `instance_eval'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.0/lib/elasticbeanstalk/executable.rb:56:in `execute!'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.0/lib/elasticbeanstalk/command.rb:213:in `block (3 levels) in exec_stage'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.0/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:169:in `call'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.0/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:169:in `exec'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.0/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:126:in `timeout_exec'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.0/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:110:in `block in create'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.0/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:109:in `instance_eval'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.0/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:109:in `create'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.0/lib/elasticbeanstalk/command.rb:209:in `block (2 levels) in exec_stage'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.0/lib/elasticbeanstalk/command.rb:207:in `each'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.0/lib/elasticbeanstalk/command.rb:207:in `each_with_index'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.0/lib/elasticbeanstalk/command.rb:207:in `block in exec_stage'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.0/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:169:in `call'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.0/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:169:in `exec'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.0/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:126:in `timeout_exec'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.0/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:110:in `block in create'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.0/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:109:in `instance_eval'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.0/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:109:in `create'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.0/lib/elasticbeanstalk/command.rb:204:in `exec_stage'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.0/lib/elasticbeanstalk/command.rb:158:in `execute!'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.0/lib/elasticbeanstalk/command.rb:68:in `run'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.0/lib/elasticbeanstalk/command-processor.rb:64:in `block (2 levels) in execute!'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.0/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:169:in `call'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.0/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:169:in `exec'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.0/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:126:in `timeout_exec'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.0/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:110:in `block in create'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.0/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:109:in `instance_eval'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.0/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:109:in `create'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.0/lib/elasticbeanstalk/command-processor.rb:62:in `block in execute!'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.0/lib/elasticbeanstalk/command-processor.rb:106:in `execute_command'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.0/lib/elasticbeanstalk/command-processor.rb:60:in `execute!'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.0/bin/command-processor:46:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/bin/command-processor:23:in `load'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/bin/command-processor:23:in `<main>'
```

> cron.config

```
files:
# Reload the on deployment
  /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/10_reload_cron.sh:
    mode: "00700"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      . /opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/envvars
      cd $EB_CONFIG_APP_CURRENT
      su -c "/usr/local/bin/bundle exec setup_cron" $EB_CONFIG_APP_USER
  # Add Bundle to the PATH
  "/etc/profile.d/bundle.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
    encoding: plain
container_commands:
  cron_01_set_leader:
    test: test ! -f /opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/.cron-setup-complete
    leader_only: true
    cwd: /var/app/ondeck
    command: su -c "/usr/local/bin/bundle exec create_cron_leader --no-update" $EB_CONFIG_APP_USER
  cron_02_write_cron_setup_complete_file:
    cwd: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles
    command: touch .cron-setup-complete
```

> policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "ec2:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "elasticloadbalancing:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "cloudwatch:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "autoscaling:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Some clue for this problem? What does mean the constant $EB_CONFIG_APP_USER, when do I define it?

Answer (score 4):

What version of Elastic Beanstalk AMI are you using? Starting with 2014.09, the old environment variables (like $EB_CONFIG_APP_USER) don't work. See the WARNING at the top of the whenever-elasticbeanstalk [readme](https://github.com/dignoe/whenever-elasticbeanstalk/blob/master/README.md) and that's gem's [Issue 18](https://github.com/dignoe/whenever-elasticbeanstalk/issues/18).

They may update the whenever-elasticbeanstalk gem to handle the new environment variable approach, but in the meantime you are probably stuck with using the default [whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever) and writing your own code to call `whenever --update`. My whenever-cron.config looks like this. Note that it doesn't handle the "leader only" option.

```
# Use the whenever gem to update webapp's crontab from config/schedule.rb after successful deployment
# See notes in Gemfile re. "whenever" vs. "whenever-elasticbeanstalk"

# Adapted from http://junkheap.net/blog/2013/05/20/elastic-beanstalk-post-deployment-scripts/
# with environment corrections from 
# http://www.dannemanne.com/posts/post-deployment_script_on_elastic_beanstalk_restart_cron-whenever

commands:
  70.1-create-post-dir:
    # "mkdir -p" ignores error if directory already exists
    command: "mkdir -p /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post"

files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/70-update_cron_from_whenever.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash

      # Load environment data
      EB_SCRIPT_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k script_dir)
      EB_SUPPORT_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k support_dir) 
      EB_APP_USER=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_user)
      EB_APP_DEPLOY_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_deploy_dir)
      # Export EB_APP_LOG_DIR so we can access it when running "whenever" below,
      # which accesses config/schedule.rb, which uses EB_APP_LOG_DIR.
      export EB_APP_LOG_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_log_dir)

      # Make sure the cron-whenever.log exists and is owned by $EB_APP_USER
      touch $EB_APP_LOG_DIR/cron-whenever.log
      chown $EB_APP_USER:$EB_APP_USER $EB_APP_LOG_DIR/cron-whenever.log

      # cron requires a home directory.  Make sure it exists and is owned by $EB_APP_USER.
      mkdir -p /home/$EB_APP_USER
      chown $EB_APP_USER:$EB_APP_USER /home/$EB_APP_USER

      # Set up correct environment and ruby version so that bundle can load all gems
      . $EB_SUPPORT_DIR/envvars
      . $EB_SCRIPT_DIR/use-app-ruby.sh

      # Run the whenever --update command to update the cron job for $EB_APP_USER.
      cd $EB_APP_DEPLOY_DIR
      whenever --update -u $EB_APP_USER

      # After setup, you can run "crontab -l -u webapp" to check the configuration.
```